# Find next character in a string?

Tags: java, date, char

I have a java programming assignment where you have to input a date on a single line and it gives you a numerology (horoscope-like) report based on the date. It is assumed that the user will enter a formatted date, separated with spaces.

I can retrieve the month, day, and year of the input by using in.nextInt(). However, I also have to check that the user used a correct separating character for each part of the date, which means I just have to check whether the user used forward slashes.

When looking at my code below, I currently use charAt() to find the separating characters. The problem is that the date won't always be 14 characters long. So a date in the form of 10 / 17 / 2004 is 14 characters long, but a date of 4 / 7 / 1992 is only 12 characters long, meaning that "slash1" won't always be in.charAt(3), in the latter situation it would be in.charAt(2).

Does java have a method that allows something like in.nextChar()? I know that it doesn't, but how could I just find a next character in the date?

**EDIT: I forgot to reflect this originally, but my professor said that we are NOT allowed to use the String.split() method, for some reason. The thing is, I get the month, day, and year perfectly fine. I just need to check that the person used a forward slash to separate the date. If a dash is entered, the date is invalid.**

```
public void getDate()
{
    char slash1, slash2;

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter your birth date (mm / dd / yyyy): ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String date = in.nextLine();

        month = in.nextInt();
        day = in.nextInt();
        year = in.nextInt();

        slash1 = date.charAt(3);
        slash2 = date.charAt(8);
    } while (validDate(slash1, slash2) == false);

    calcNum();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Scanner just to get a line. Then split() the line on whitespace and check the fields:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class GetDate {

   int month, day, year;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      GetDate theApp = new GetDate();
      theApp.getDate();

   }

   public void getDate()
   {
      String date;
      do
      {
         System.out.print("Please enter your birth date (mm / dd / yyyy): ");
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         date = in.nextLine();
      } while (validDate(date) == false);


      calcNum();
   }

   boolean validDate(String date)
   {
      // split the string based on white space
      String [] fields = date.split("\\s");

      // must have five fields
      if ( fields.length != 5 )
      {
         return false;
      }

      // must have '/' separators
      if ( ! ( fields[1].equals("/") && fields[3].equals("/") ) )
         return false;

      // must have integer strings
      if ( ! ( Pattern.matches("^\\d*$", fields[0]) && 
               Pattern.matches("^\\d*$", fields[2]) &&
               Pattern.matches("^\\d*$", fields[4]) ) )
         return false;

      // data was good, convert strings to integer 
      // should also check for integer within range at this point
      month = Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
      day = Integer.parseInt(fields[2]);
      year = Integer.parseInt(fields[4]);

      return true;
   }

   void calcNum() {}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned this earlier in my question. This is exactly what I need, but my teacher said we are not allowed to use the String.split() method for some reason. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Screw it, I'm using String.split(). Thanks!

Comment: @homersimpson I added another answer that doesn't use split.

Answer (score 1):

you could consider to split the input date string with `" / "`, then you get a String array. the next step is converting each string in that array to int.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than thinking about what characters are used as separators, focus on the content you want, which is digits.

This code splits on *non* digits, do it doesn't matter how many digits are in each group or what characters are used as separators:

```
String[] parts = input.split("\\D+");
```

It's also hardly any code, so there's much less chance for a bug.

Now that you have the numerical parts in the String[], you can get on with your calculations.

Here's some code you could use following the above split:

```
if (parts.length != 3) {
    // bad input
}

// assuming date entered in standard format of dd/mm/yyyy
// and not in retarded American format, but it's up to you
int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[0];
int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1];
int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Look ahead in the stream to make sure it contains what you expect.

```
private static final Pattern SLASH = Pattern.compile("\\s*/\\s*");

static SomeTypeYouMadeToHoldCalendarDate getDate() {
  while (true) { /* Might want to give user a way to quit. */
    String line = 
      System.console().readLine("Please enter your birth date (mm / dd / yyyy): ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(line);
    if (!in.hasNextInt())
      continue;
    int month = in.nextInt();
    if (!in.hasNext(SLASH)
      continue;
    in.next(SLASH);
    ...
    if (!validDate(month, day, year))
      continue;
    return new SomeTypeYouMadeToHoldCalendarDate(month, day, year);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses Scanner methods to parse:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class TestScanner {

   int month, day, year;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      TestScanner theApp = new TestScanner();   
      theApp.getDate();
      theApp.calcNum();
   }

   public void getDate()
   {
      int fields = 0;
      String delim1 = "";
      String delim2 = "";
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      do
      {
         fields = 0;
         System.out.print("Please enter your birth date (mm / dd / yyyy): ");
         while ( fields < 5 && in.hasNext() )
         {
            try {
               fields++;
               switch (fields)
               {
                  case 1:
                     month = in.nextInt();
                     break;
                  case 3:
                     day = in.nextInt();
                     break;
                  case 5:
                     year = in.nextInt();
                     break;
                  case 2:
                     delim1 = in.next();
                     break;
                  case 4:
                     delim2 = in.next();
                     break;
               }
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e)
            {
               System.out.println("ERROR: Field " + fields + " must be an integer");
               String temp = in.nextLine();
               fields = 6;
               break;
            }
         }
      } while ( fields != 5 || validDate(delim1, delim2) == false);
      in.close();
      System.out.println("Input date: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
   }   

   boolean validDate(String delim1, String delim2)
   {
      if ( ( !  delim1.equals("/") ) || ( ! delim2.equals("/") ) ) 
      {
         System.out.println("ERROR: use '/' as the date delimiter");
         return false;
      }
      if ( month < 1 || month > 12 )  
      {
         System.out.println("Invalid month value: " + month);
         return false;
      }
      if (  day < 1 || day > 31 ) 
      {
         System.out.println("Invalid day value: " + day);
         return false;  
      }
      if (  year < 1 || year > 3000 ) 
      {
         System.out.println("Invalid year: " + year);
         return false;  
      }
      return true;
   }

   void calcNum()
   {

   }

}
```